# Node Express - Handle Form data BEFORE multer saves files

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I want to do following:

1. User creates a request using a FORM
2. The Form contains Input Fields and multipart files
3. First I want to validate the input fields using `express validator`
4. Afterwards, if the inputs are valid I want to save the multipart files using `multer`

My Problem: If I try to access the input fields BEFORE multer has parsed them, then the input fields will be undefined. If I try to access the input fields AFTER multer parsed them, then the input fields are accessible, but the files are already saved before I can validate the input fields

Currently my middleware gets executed in this order:
`app.post('/upload', upload.array('files', 50), uploadFormValidation, uploadController.postUpload);`

I want to execute the middleware in this order:
`app.post('/upload', uploadFormValidation, upload.array('files', 50), uploadController.postUpload);`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Having the same problem right now :/. Did you figure it out?

Comment: @ArkashVijayakumar no sorry. I dont think its possible to do this with multer

Comment: Ah, I thought so. Thanks anyway!